# When running a Jmeter test in a Docker instance in Azure Devops, running similar samplers sequentially prevents execution beyond the first

Tags: azure, docker, jmeter

I am trying to run a test where I make 82 separate requests, all identical except for one header value.  The test works properly when run locally but either because of Docker or Azure Devops, I am running into this error.  Below is the raw test report text, where you can see that only one of the MobileAsync/Confirm requests is being called.  Logging using processors shows that preprocessors will log for every sampler (including the ones that apparently do not execute), but postprocessors only log for the samplers that appear to execute.

```
...
1623266094052,65,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094119,63,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094184,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094250,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094316,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094382,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094448,66,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094516,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266094582,65,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266099667,66,manifest.json HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266104748,1,Assert all modelObjects have been found,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266104779,18,JSR223 Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
1623266104797,83,MobileAsync/Confirm HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true
qa.azurewebsites.net/MobileAsync/Confirm,83,0,0
1623266104911,67,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266104997,63,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266105062,65,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266105128,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266105194,62,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266105258,63,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
1623266105322,64,manifest.json HTTP Request,304,The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.,Thread Group 1-1,,true
...
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried modifying the Login request and putting it in a Simple Controller.

As I was using a ForEach Controller to make the 14 calls, I "hard-coded" the loop.

I added a timer to the sampler, thinking that perhaps there was a failsafe in Docker/Azure Devops built to prevent the same request being sent more than required.

I am in the middle of testing Blazemeter's Parallel Controller, trying to get JMeter plugins working in Docker.

I have tried moving the sampler out of its old ForEach Controller into a new one.

**Test**

Here is an image of the test, if it helps.

[image: Image of Test/ForEach Controller]

Answer (score 1):

[ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) takes the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
var_3=baz
etc.
```

and it stops when:

- `End index for loop` is reached
- there are no more variables to iterate

whatever comes the first

So I would recommend checking JMeter Variables names/values

1. Put [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere before the ForEach Controller
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.entrySet().each {var -> 
       log.info(var.key + '=' + var.value)
   }
   ```

   in the above code `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and `log` is for [Log4jLogger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/apidocs/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.html), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on these and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements
3. After running your test inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) - it will contain all the variables available, you may spot other suspicious entries there, my expectation is that you have only one variable to iterate

If you won't be able to troubleshoot the issue yourself - update your question with your ForEach Controller configuration and jmeter.log file contents

Comment: I was relatively certain I had already checked this, but it had been a while, so I double-checked and all of the objects being iterated through are generated correctly.  I mentioned this in my original post, but within each iteration of the for loop the preprocessors all execute but the samplers and postprocessors do not (I don't know if that's expected behavior).  Also, I use other ForEach Controllers that use the same criteria as this one that work correctly.